# in AIML using a <star/> tag to get a <condition> tag to work?

Tags: aiml

[image]

so when this code is run through a program that asks it for specific answers tied to said questions it will find the category but just return whatever the value of  is not the description from each condition tag.

and due to this I have no clue on how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are testing for different values of the same predicate, you can do it like this.

```
<category>
<pattern>WHAT IS *</pattern>
    <template>
    <think><set name="state"><star/></set></think>
    <condition name="state">
        <li value="long term knowledge">Long term knowledge is valid every time a programme is run.</li>
        <li value="short term knowledge">Short term knowledge is only valid for a particular instance or run of a programme.</li>
        <li value="generic knowledge">blah blah blah</li>
        <li value="domain specific knowledge">blah blah blah</li>
        <li value="a fact">A fact is a statement which asserts that a relationship holds for a object-subject pair.</li>
        <li value="a rule">rule information</li>
    </condition>
    </template>
</category>
```

For future reference, please include your code rather than a screenshot of it, as it make it so much easier to copy/paste in order to help.

Comment: thanks for the help i have tried the method you are suggesting however the outcome i get is still the input thats in the <star> tag?

Comment: What interpreter are you using? Pandorabots or something else? Please post your exact code and a sample of the conversation where it does this.

Comment: im on something called jupyterhub, and this code is then added to a auto marker program that randomly asks the my code questions and checks for the expected outcome so i have no way of finding the conversation sadly

Comment: also i am not allowed to directly post pictures as my rep is too low?

Comment: Unfortunately, you need to check with jupyterhub, as this code is valid AIML and will work in an AIML interpreter.